# Polygon division by multiple surfaces in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, surface

Image for example. For plan and csv file.
The final result, initially it was a large polygon that was divided according to the surfaces.

[image]

Data in the csv file
[image]

I want to detach the polygon according to the surfaces in the csv file.

Is there a way to split a polygon according to several surfaces at the same time?

I am a topographer and I would like to do this to be able to create cadastral plans for a certain sector where I know surface data for several parcels. This several surfaces are in a CSV file with another attributes. Like person or parcel number.

Comment: There are infinite ways to partition a polygon. Please add a graphic to show what you have in mind.

Comment: See [Vector Overlay](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html)

Comment: I edit the post